# How to get Distinct Sum at SSRS Expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

[image: Tabel Data and Expected Result]
Please check the picture file attached. I want to get distinct sum of a column(Promotion Amount) based on another column(Promotion Name). At SSRS.
Cannot do this grouping sum at t-sql Level .. Need to be done in SSRS only.. through expression.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: doesn't make much sense, do you need a total for each promotion amount? how will the report look like? in the example, where did you get the 150 in expected result from?

Comment: I've two Promotion Budgets ,A and B... Against that money is spent. A budget values is 100 and B is 50.. It makes 150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved. Grouped by "Promotion Name". Then Write Sum formula as `SUM(Max(PromotionAmount,"GroupName"))`